# Telerik RadChart and Ektron CMS 7.6 dll conflict

Tags: telerik, conflict, ektron, radchart

I have Ektron CMS 7.6 which includes a plethora of built in features. One of those features is Telerik for ASP.NET Ajax Controls.

Also I have a subscription for Telerik Controls separately.

Problem is Telerik was forced to break some backwards compatiblity for the Radchart involving Telerik.Charting.dll and RadChart.Net2.dll. basically these two dlls reference the same classes and can not coexist. My tool kit uses the newer RadChart.

Has anybody else ran accross this? How did you fix it?

exact error:

```
    The type 'Telerik.Charting.ChartSeries' exists in both
    'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
     Files\internetcms\84aae664\ef33a0e2\assembly\dl3\79307436\
    00e4973e_e51cc901\
    RadChart.Net2.DLL' 

    and 

    'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
 Files\internetcms\84aae664\ef33a0e2\assembly\dl3\f477bd61\e6a2b770_714ec901\
    Telerik.Charting.DLL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the RadChart.Net2.dll from the project gets rid of the build error.

not 100% sure that the older dll is not needed for something else in Ektron.

Now I have added the handler to the web.config but Ektron catches it as an unknown file and redirects to my error page.

added to web.config

```
   <add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler,
 Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2008.2.826.20, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="false" />
```

Any other suggestions would be helpful

also: yes I am aware that Telerik is up to 2009.1.*.* but I don't want to add anymore complexity to my issue until I get this working first

Final Update Fixed!

the handler above just needed to by moved to the top of the handlers section. @dsbarka from Ektron was able to suggest this one to me. Possible that something within Ektron might have been trapping the handler for the chart image.

Working now

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience with Ektron CMS400 that, if they include something out of the box, you're stuck with that version until they feel like upgrading...otherwise you're going to break more of CMS400 than the new functionality is worth.

Unfortunately, I'd say that you'd be better off re-engineering your RadChart toolkit to use the version of the Telerik tools that Ektron includes in CMS400.